# Do you see the top card of your deck when you play Mickey Mouse - Detective?

Tags: lorcana

When [Mickey Mouse Detective](https://www.tcgplayer.com/product/508863/lorcana-tcg-the-first-chapter-mickey-mouse-detective?Language=English)<sup>1</sup> is played, do you get to look at the top card of your deck and decide whether to ink it or not? Or do you just decide whether you want to ink it or not without knowing the card?

1. Card text: **Get a clue:**  When you play this character, you may put the top card of your deck into your inkwell facedown and exerted.

Comment: I won't post as an actual answer since I don't have an official ruling, but in these kinds of games the general rule is "if it doesn't say you can, you can't" so I'm guessing the answer is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not get to look at it.

A [message on X from the DisneyLorcana account](https://twitter.com/DisneyLorcana/status/1649513447594270720):

> Apr 21, 2023
>
> if an ability (Like one jump ahead) puts the top card of your deck facedown into your inkwell, you don't get to see what card that was.